# Kafka MirrorMaker2 automated consumer offset sync

Tags: apache-kafka, strimzi, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am using MirrorMaker2 for DR.

Kafka 2.7 should support
[automated consumer offset sync](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-545:+support+automated+consumer+offset+sync+across+clusters+in+MM+2.0)

Here is the yaml file I am using (I use strimzi for creating it)

[image: Code]

All source cluster topics are replicated in destination cluster.
Also **...checkpoint.internal** topic is created in destination cluster that contains all source cluster offsets synced, BUT I don't see these offsets being translated into destination cluster **_consumer_offsets** topic which means when I will start consumer (same consumer group) in destination cluster it will start reading messages from the beginning.

My expectation is that after allowing automated consumer offsets sync all consumer offsets from source clusters translated and stored in _consumer_offsets topic in the destination cluster.

Can someone please clarify if my expectation is correct and if not how it should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `sync.group.offsets.enabled` setting is for `MirrorCheckpointConnector`.

I'm not entirely sure how Strimzi runs MirrorMaker 2 but I think you need to set it like:

```yaml
checkpointConnector:
  config:
    checkpoints.topic.replication.factor: 1
    sync.group.offsets.enabled: "true"
```

Comment: It works now. Thank you very much for pointing me to the problem.