# In Kafka DNS configuration, are there any source applications to look at?

Tags: apache-kafka, flume

## env

- apache kafka 2.7
- apache flume 1.9.0

## trouble

I'm gonna setup kafka cluster with version 2.7.
Using DNS attribute(`use_all_dns_ips`), I want to perform traffic switching by dividing the dns of both clusters in case of DR.
But now, i using Apache Flume tailing source. **I cannot apply DNS attribute values in flume because flume channel doesn't support DNS properties.**

I also looked for the kafka source connector, but in the official version, there seems to be only a spooldir version and no tailing source version.
Is there any tailing source application that you can recommend to add a dns attribute?

Comment: I don't think that property does what you think because offsets are still tracked _per cluster_, so there's no DR scenario where a consumer will recover correctly

Comment: Sure, but I was specifically talking about Flume

Comment: I'm gonna use dns per cluster. And MirrorMaker2 consumer offset sync. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65925842/kafka-mirrormaker2-automated-consumer-offset-sync
Is it an impossible theory? I referrenced this article too.
https://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=4074

Comment: Oh, i see. thanks always.

Comment: Flume ought to act as any regular producer/consumer client, as its Java code at the end of the day using `kafka-clients` dependency. That being said, you should be able to set any client properties you want, so what do you mean "doesn't support" it?

Comment: Yes, i checked this docs. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLUME-3281
Flume supports kafka client 2.0.1 version compatibility. But dns property works over 2.1.0 version. So I updated kafka-client to ver 2.1.0, but kafka-channel dns property doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235320/discussion-between-hoon-and-onecricketeer).

Comment: I haven't really used Flume since like version 1.6... Filebeat, Logstash, Rsyslog, Fluentd, etc have all been used instead with Kafka where I've worked on rotating log files